# trying to organize Google Drive cloud and cannot sync due to crash recovery - how can i see the size of each folder in one place? and subs?

Tags: windows-10, google-drive

Windows 10 post crash of update.  How the heck can I see what is left of Google Drive as it was synced. I am afraid to sync as I might be trading damaged files for good ones.  I have GD desktop. But the same is true for the C drive and other clouds as One Drive.

Comment: Hello, please construct your question in a more understandable way. Can't ou just check the status of your drive online? Not sure what the problem here is.